# Choose gcc version to compile vmware modules

Tags: compiling, gcc, vmware

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 , and I manually upgraded my kernel version to `4.12.8` using the tool `ukuu` (Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility).

When trying to launch `vmware` (it is already installed), it asks me to give it the path to `gcc-7.1` to compile `vmware` modules.

[image]

I didn't understand why `vmware` asked me that, because I installed the `vmware` modules without any problem in the previous kernel versions in the same computer.

After some researches, I found out that `vmware` compile its modules using the same `gcc` version that is used to compile the current kernel. As I installed this kernel version manually, I didn't have `gcc-7.1` on my computer.

My question is (sorry for this long speech I had to give) : How can I force `vmware` to use another gcc version to compile its modules ?

Comment: can you install GCC version 7.1.0 first, then provide VMware the path to that GCC version?

Comment: There is no `gcc-7.1` in the official repository. I did find another repository (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`) but it didn't contain gcc 7.1.0 .

Comment: I think you should be able to download the tarball and compile it from source if needed. Tarball is located at https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-7.1.0/

Comment: There is no way to force vmware to use another `gcc` version ?

Comment: @Sidahmed `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/gcc-7.1`

Comment: @GAD3R it looks like this repository is dead, because this is what `apt update` gives me : `Err:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/gcc-7.1/ubuntu zesty Release                                                              
  404  Not Found`

Comment: @TimothyPulliam I think the best move is to install gcc 7.1.0 from source like you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: you should not.

**Long answer**:

That's not that VMware stubbornly wants a particular GCC version for no reason. It's very unwise to compile a kernel module with another GCC than the one used for the kernel itself: if there is any ABI change between the two gcc versions, you will probably corrupt and crash your system.

If you ever convinced VMware to compile its modules with your GCC version, the kernel would refuse to load them. You would then have to binary-edit the modules in order to replace the GCC signature with the right one.

But, all in all, is that worth the risk? It would be preferable to either download/compile GCC 7.1, or recompile your kernel with your current GCC version.

Answer (score 1):

Adding my comment as an answer since it answered your question.

I think you should be able to download the tarball and compile it from source if needed. Tarball is located at https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-7.1.0/

Download the tarball then run the usual `./configure`, `make`, `make install`

Comment: Better pass `--program-suffix=-7.1` to `../gcc-7.1.0/configure` and never build GCC inside its source tree.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch I know this is a stupid question, but why never build GCC inside the source tree? Is the build process different for GCC? Or this simply best practice for compiling from source in general?

Comment: Because it is [documented](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html) as a must (more precisely, a strong recommendation). The inside source tree build is not tested by GCC developers and is likely to break something.

Comment: you should edit your answer to add that precision

Comment: [Here is a Good tutorial](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/10/07/building-gcc-ubuntu-linux) to build gcc 7.1. Follow this